# Intent filter to open xls and xlsx files

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want attachment of my email having xls and xlsx file to be opened with my Android App. Currently I am able to open csv file from my app. Please help.
Code I am using in my manifest for csv is :

```
    <intent-filter
                    android:icon='@drawable/rr_ipad1_icon'
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                     android:priority='1'>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" /> 
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
                 <data android:mimeType="text/csv" />  
                 <data android:pathPattern="*.csv" />

            </intent-filter>

             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/csv" android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.csv" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/csv" android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.csv" />


              </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xls" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*..*.xls" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*..*.xls" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*..*.xls" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*..*.xls" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*..*.xls" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*.xls" /> 
     </intent-filter>
```

and same for xlsx